# How to print a specific line from a list using user's input as search in java

Tags: java, list, search, javafx

I have a textfield named searchtext and thats the users input. On button click i search a list with 9126 values imported from a csv file and i want to print the line that has the user's input on a label.

```
    public void search(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);            //I have a file named "something.csv"
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }                                               //now i have all 9126 lines in the list
    String search = searchtext.getText().replaceAll("\\s", ""); //searchtext is the users input
    if (list.contains(search)){
        //PRINT THE LINE THAT CONTAINS WHAT THE USER WROTE
    }
}
```

To be exact in what i need:  Inside my list i have this value `1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy`. What i want is when the user types `Toy` in the search field `1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy` will be printed out on the label. I created a test to check if `Toy` is read by the `.contains()` like so:

```
if (list.contains(search)){
        //PRINT THE LINE THAT CONTAINS WHAT THE USER WROTE
        System.out.println("in the list");
    }else{
        System.out.println("outside the list");
    }
```

But is get `"outside the list"` if i dont type exactly `1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy`. So i guess my question is how to create a method that searches the list for a keyword, and prints out that line.

Comment: Note that `list` is an array of strings. You obviously need to loop through every element in `list` and use `contains` in that loop.

Comment: So, you have no idea how to "print" or you have no idea how to find the correct line to "print?" Also, "print" is so generic, what exactly is that supposed to do?

Comment: If `list.contains(search)` is true, then the line containing the search text is exactly equal to `search`. So all you would need is `label.setText(search)`. But perhaps that is not the logic you intended, even if it is the logic you have written.

Comment: Or perhaps you are looking for the line number (`list.indexOf(search)`)?

Comment: @James_D i edited my question, i hope it's more clear now

Comment: @jai i have no idea how to print

Comment: So what is wrong with the answer provided below? And we have no idea what you mean by "print".

Comment: @James_D it doesn't work, my label has no text when i press the button. When i say "print" i meant that my Label `getmovie` will have the text  `1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy` when i press the button and `Toy` is in the search field

Comment: If it doesn't work, you have something else wrong in your code somewhere.

Comment: @James_D okay it worked, thanks for your help, sorry for the trouble. I used `Files.lines(file.toPath()).filter(line -> line.contains(search)).findFirst().ifPresent(label::setText)‌​;` and got what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might be interested
`Files.lines(file.toPath()).filter(line -> line.contains(search)).findFirst().ifPresent(searchtextarea::setText)‌​;` only sets the first line that the list might contains, even if you use `.findAny()`. But what if you have more lines that have the word you are looking for?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).contains(search)) {
                searchtextarea.appendText(list.get(i) + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Using this for loop i was able to get any line that had the specific word i was looking for. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

the most straightforward way would be to loop through all lines and break once you find a matching result (if you are interested in only the first result)

```
for (String line : list) {
    if (line.contains(search)){
        //PRINT THE LINE THAT CONTAINS WHAT THE USER WROTE
        return;
    }
}
// HANDLE EMPTY RESULT
```

alternatively you can also use java 8 streams to find the first element matching a condition

```
String result = list.stream().filter(line -> line.contains(search))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
if ( result == null ) {
    // HANDLE EMPTY RESULT
    return;
}
// DO SOMETHING WITH THE LINE CONTAINING WHAT THE USER WROTE
```

Comment: If you're using streams, you can omit the scanner and the list entirely: `Files.lines(file.toPath()).filter(line -> line.contains(search)).findFirst().ifPresent(label::setText);`. Assuming this is what the OP wanted, of course...